# Term for a problem that you are trying to solve is already solved by others

Tags: terminology

I've come across that term once. It was from an article. And the term is somewhat like "Collective" or "Crowd" + some other words.

Basically, a problem that you are trying to solve is already solved by others. Just that the solver isn't aware of the solution existed.

I've read through the following thread, but I still can't find the word I am working for. I will be much appreciated if anyone can help me find the answer. 
Thanks.

[An English idiom for "solve a problem that has been solved"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198530/an-english-idiom-for-solve-a-problem-that-has-been-solved)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the term you are looking for is ***multiple discovery*** or perhaps ***convergent invention***

Answer (score 0):

Consider: "**Why re-invent the wheel**?" or "**They just re-invented the wheel.**"

To "re-invent the wheel" means to make an unnecessary or needless effort because someone else has already done or accomplished the same thing.  (google your favorite dictionary...)

Irrespective of whether the subject is aware of their folly or not , it communicates that point to a third party observer.

Comment: We appreciate it if you could define your suggestion and explain why you think it's a good fit. Personally, I don't think this works, as the OP clearly states the person isn't aware it's solved already.

Comment: I agree with @Catija. What's more to "reinvent the wheel" is the most upvoted answer in the question that the OP has already searched through and said that none of the answers provided there suit their needs.

Comment: I should've read the question more carefully.