# swatting flies with a sledge hammer

Tags: expressions

Is the phrase "swatting flies with a sledge hammer" a proper way to say that something is a litle bit too complicated?

Comment: Similar expression in Spanish: "matar moscas a cañonazos" ("to kill flies with a cannon").

Comment: The more usual expression in English is "Use a sledgehammer to crack a nut". As has been said by Jason Bassford this means to use unnecessary force rather than to use an over-complicated solution. Having said that using Excel to work out everyone's share of a meal for four would be described as "Using a sldgehammer to crack a nut".'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's an idiom for doing something in an unnecessarily complicated way?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43372/whats-an-idiom-for-doing-something-in-an-unnecessarily-complicated-way)

Answer (score 1):

No, because [what it means](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut.html) is to use disproportionate force or expense to overcome a minor problem.

**its a bit complicated** should suffice.

Comment: thank you. I actually meant what you wrote:)

Answer (score 1):

No.

*Swatting flies with a sledge hammer* would be an example of [**overkill**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overkill):

> **1** : a destructive capacity greatly exceeding that required for a given target
>   **2** : an excess of something (such as a quantity or an action) beyond what is required or suitable for a particular purpose
>   // publicity *overkill*
>   // an *overkill* in weaponry

---

The following might be an example of something too *complicated*:

> I swatted a fly with a 6-foot-long Meccano set construction I'd built with two plungers, five rubber bands, a car battery, and an alarm clock.

While, yes, this might *also* be considered overkill, the hammer solution is very simplistic—while this is very complicated.