# Idiom for making a task unnecessarily complicated

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Are there any idioms for making something less easy to understand, or for unnecessarily complicating a straightforward task?

My favorites for this scenario:

- Don't muddy the waters...
- Let's not boil the ocean like last time...

Maybe something water-body related, but probably not. I'm thinking more useful in a workplace scenario, but it would be cool if I could somehow work it into casual conversation too.

Comment: Of course you know that “boil the ocean” doesn’t mean “to over complicate”

Comment: Does [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43372/whats-an-idiom-for-doing-something-in-an-unnecessarily-complicated-way?rq=1) answer your question? Or what about [one of these](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/43372?lq=1)?

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting a phrase or idiom, but why overcomplicate things? Just say **overcomplicate**.

> overcomplicate: to complicate exessively ([thefreedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/overcomplicate))